# Corona SDK array index is beyond array bounds, advice needed

Tags: arrays, lua, coronasdk, lua-table

I will try to as concise as possible with my issue.

Firstly, files are:

```
block.lua
base.lua
main.lua
```

In block.lua I create a block, add collision detection and a cleanup code.
In base.lua I create a base made up of 4 columns and 10 rows. 40 blocks in total.
In main.lua I create 4 bases made from the base.class.

All is working fine once the game begins. 
I remove the bases and call them again on level 2.
They create themselves ok BUT
when the enemy is destroyed once again, and the bases are to be rebuilt, I get an:

```
array index 1 is beyond array bounds:1..1
```

-- all the way up to--

```
array index 800 is beyond array bounds:1..159
```

it  will then create the bases and continue until the enemys are destroyed and do the same again starting at :

```
array index 800 is beyond array bounds:1..159
```

-- all the way up to--

```
array index 4000 is beyond array bounds:1..159
```

The terminal points me at block.lua line 23

```
blockGroup:insert(blockNum,self.block)
```

Now I cant see anything wrong in the class, I have looked and googled for hours but all to no avail.
I would really appreciate a helping hand to guide me here please.
I have tried rewriting the "cleanup" etc but no joy.
I left a few commented out bits in there and removed some of the irrelevant stuff.
I post below the relevant code:

```
--MAIN.LUA--

function gameOver()
  Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", onEnterFrame)
  Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", movePlayer)

  layers:removeSelf()
  layers = nil

  enemyCount = 0

   for i = 1,#allEnemys do
     timer.cancel(allEnemys[i].clock)
     Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", allEnemys[i] )
     display.remove(allEnemys[i].image)
     allEnemys[i].image=nil
   end
     allEnemys=nil

cleanupBlocks()
   end
----------------------------------------------------------------------
              -- LEVEL UP --
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
function levelUp(level)
enemyCount = 0

local enemys = require("modules.enemy")
    if allEnemys ~= nil then
      for i = 1,#allEnemys do
           timer.cancel(allEnemys[i].clock)
           Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", allEnemys[i] )
           display.remove(allEnemys[i].image)
           allEnemys[i].image=nil
      end
    end
           allEnemys=nil
 cleanupBlocks()
 levels()

 end
----------------------------------------------------------------------
              -- LEVELS --
----------------------------------------------------------------------
function levels(level)

function createInvader(x, y, row)
  for j = 1, 2 do
    for i = 1, 2 do
      if allEnemys == nil then
       allEnemys = {}
      else
       enemysCount=#allEnemys
      end
      allEnemys[#allEnemys + 1] = enemys:new()
      allEnemys[#allEnemys ]:init(i * 60, j * 70 + 70,j) 
      allEnemys[#allEnemys ]:start()
    end
  end
end
createInvader()

--[[function createBases1()

local base = require("modules.base")
  for i = 1, 4 do
    base:new()
    base:init(i * 180 - 130, 850)
  end
end  ]]--

createBases()
end
```

--BLOCK.LUA--

```
local block = {}
local block_mt = { __index = block}
local scene = scene
local blockGroup = display.newGroup()
local blockNum = 0


function block:new() -- constructor
local group = {}
return setmetatable( group, block_mt )
end

function block:init(xloc,yloc) --initializer
-- Create attributes

self.block = display.newRect( xloc,yloc,10,10)
self.block:setFillColor ( 2, 255, 14  )

blockNum = blockNum + 1
blockGroup:insert(blockNum,self.block)

local blockCollisionFilter = { categoryBits = 128, maskBits = 387}
physics.addBody( self.block,  "static", {filter = blockCollisionFilter})
self.count = 1

end
function cleanupBlocks()

--[[ print(blockNum, blockGroup.numChildren)
for i=1,blockGroup.numChildren do
blockGroup[1]:removeSelf()
blockGroup[1] = nil
end  ]]--
print(blockNum, blockGroup.numChildren)
while blockGroup.numChildren>0 do

  display.remove(blockGroup[1])
  blockGroup[1]=nil
end

end

function block:start()
---  Create Listeneres
 self.block:addEventListener( "collision", self )
 scene:addEventListener('base_block_event', self)
end

return block
```

--BASE.LUA--

```
local base = {}
local base_mt = { __index = base}
local scene = scene

local block = require("modules.block")

function base:new() -- constructor
local group = {}
return setmetatable( group, base_mt )
end

function base:init(xloc, yloc) --initializer
-- Create attributes
local base

for j = 1, 4 do
    for i = 1, 10 do
        base = block:new()
        base:init(xloc+i * 10,yloc+j * 10)
        base:start()

    end
end

end

return base
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you use

```
blockNum = blockNum + 1
blockGroup:insert(blockNum,self.block)
```

Try to use

```
blockGroup:insert(self.block)
```

just to see if you still get that error.